# Are there any standard apps in iOS that implement isIdleTimerDisabled=true?

Tags: ios, sleep-wake

I'm wondering if any of the built-in applications in iOS have [isIdleTimerDisabled set to true](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623070-isidletimerdisabled) at any time?

If so, which app, and how do you get in the state to activate it?

Note - if an app is in this state, it will have its display stay on, and never turn off while the app is active.

**Why do I want to know this?**

I have a company iPhone that has the auto sleep option set so the phone's display locks after ~ 2 or 3 min, and it can't be set to "Never" sleep due to company policy lockdown.

But one day I noticed that if I had a certain app open, the display never went to sleep. I did some research, and it appears the app is using the  isIdleTimerDisabled feature to keep the display on permanently, if the app is in the foreground.

The benefit of this is that it allows me to receive 2FA notifications on my phone and approve them *without leaving the app* that's keeping the display awake.

This works for me, as I own this paid app, but I'd like to share this idea with others on my team, preferably using a built in app, so no one has to install anything.

Note if none of the built in apps support this, are there well known, trusted, 3rd party apps that do this as well? YouTube or Netflix come to mind, but I'd like it to be something people wouldn't mind running on their phone *at work* and having their boss see it!

Comment: Which practical problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Good point - I've added a note to the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I haven't found any built in apps that do this, I guess it can be done in Safari using a glitch/hack.

This demo page utilizes the hack, and clicking the button on the page keeps the page awake forever.

https://richtr.github.io/NoSleep.js/example/

It is open source, and works on all iOs versions [except for 13.4](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js/issues/85), but will probably be fixed for that too as well!

Note that it may not work as well as a native app though, as I find that if my power is low and I'm not plugged in, this doesn't work (display turns off)

Answer (score 1):

The app [Ultimate Guitar](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/ultimate-guitar-chords-tabs/id357828853?app=itunes&ign-mpt=uo%3D4) prevents the screen to dim/the phone to lock when viewing a tab. This helps reading the tab while playing the guitar.

As we discovered in the comments, the build-in Wallet App takes roughly two minutes when a card with a qr code is selected. This can be longer than the set sleep duration in preferences, but ultimately won't prevent the phone to sleep.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I tried this, and couldnt get it to work... I had a credit card displayed, and it eventually fell asleep. I also tried to have it so it was ready to scan the card ("Hold near reader"), but it stopped doing that after a bit, then went to sleep as well.

Comment: and I just checked with `Ultimate Guitar`, and it works if you're on a tab page, like you suggested.

Comment: You are right about the Wallet App. Apparently it just takes longer than the sleep time set in preferences. I changed my answer accordingly.